# minify js and styles in laravel 5

Tags: laravel, minify, laravel-mix

How can I minify my JavaScript and css files all in one?

currently I have:

```
let mix = require('laravel-mix');

mix.styles([
  'theme/admin/assets/css/bootstrap.css',
  'theme/admin/assets/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css',
  'theme/admin/assets/css/zabuto_calendar.css',
  'theme/admin/assets/lineicons/style.css',
  'theme/admin/assets/css/style.css',
  'theme/admin/assets/css/style-responsive.css',
  'css/adminstyle.css'
], 'public/css/admin.css');

mix.scripts([
  'theme/admin/assets/js/jquery.min.js',
  'theme/admin/assets/js/bootstrap.min.js',
  'theme/admin/assets/js/jquery.dcjqaccordion.2.7.js',
  'theme/admin/assets/js/jquery.scrollTo.min.js',
  'theme/admin/assets/js/jquery.nicescroll.js',
  'theme/admin/assets/js/jquery.sparkline.js',
  'theme/admin/assets/js/common-scripts.js',
  'theme/admin/assets/js/zabuto_calendar.js'
], 'public/js/admin.js');
```

in my `webpack.mix.js` file but it creates empty files.

Comment: is `theme` a *parent* directory or what? is it the same level as public?

Comment: @Wreigh theme is folder inside public folder

Comment: then prepend `public` in all styles and scripts in the `theme` directory.

Comment: i'll try.......

Comment: @Wreigh it works thank you. please share answer i'll confirm it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use full path *starting* from the root directory of your Laravel application.

So instead of:

```
'theme/admin/assets/css/bootstrap.css'
```

As you've said that `theme` is under `public`, you should do this:

```
'public/theme/admin/assets/css/bootstrap.css'
```

Do this update on the rest of your **URL**s